# SQL Server IIF() function works even with compatibility level 100

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2016 Express instance, and a database with compatibility level=100 (SQL Server 2008).

I ran this query on that database:

```
SELECT IIF(2 > 1, 'yes','no')
```

I expected the query to fail, because `IIF()` wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2012 (compatibility level 110). However, the query succeeds and outputs `yes`.

Why does it work?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding compatibility levels are for allowing you to migrate your databases easier, so some features from higher versions might work on lower compatibility levels. Please check this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44908/what-is-the-actual-behavior-of-compatibility-level-80) from dbaexchange. It sheds light on the issue.

Comment: Since we have many installations with sql server 2008, I put compatibility = 100 in order to immediately receive error reports in the developer environment if I use non-compatible queries

Answer (score 0):

The fact that IIF is translated into CASE also has an impact on other aspects of the behavior of this function. Since CASE expressions can be nested only up to the level of 10, IIF statements can also be nested only up to the maximum level of 10